# What is "Repository Group" in SourceTree?

Tags: git, repository, mercurial, bitbucket.org

Regarding the [SourceTree app](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) for [Mercurial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)/Git version-control management, what exactly does the `New Repository Group` menu item do? What is a repository group?

[image]

I looked through the doc and did some googling, but no mention found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just to sort your repositories within groups.
This looks like a file explorer (the "folders" created are just virtual ones).

Comment: Can you cite some documentation?

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-4304?attachmentSortBy=dateTime

Comment: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-4504

Comment: The documentation is a bit outdated but the principle is still the same : https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/bookmarks-column-repository-browser-overview-781398414.html#BookmarksColumn/RepositoryBrowserOverview-Manipulatingrepositorylists